# How to subtract each Int value based on some condition in an array by a constant in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array ["11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23"]

How can I subtract Int value which is greater than 12 of this array in Swift?
So array becomes ["11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11"] like this

my current workaround is

```
func test() {
        let hours = "11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23|13-17,20-24|11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23"
        var firstHalf : [String] = []
               var secondHalf : [String] = []
               let split = hours.components(separatedBy: "|")
               for i in 0..<split.count {
                   let index = split[i].components(separatedBy: ",")
                   firstHalf.append(index[0])
                   secondHalf.append(index[1])
               }
               print(firstHalf)
               print(secondHalf)
               
               let final  = firstHalf.first?.components(separatedBy: "-")
               print(final?[0])
               print(final?[1])
    }
```

Comment: add you login below `final` convert value to int n check if its > 12, it it subtract from 12.

Comment: Convert your string to an array of "TimeRangeOrWhatever" structures declaring some logic functions and convert back to string for display. Nobody will ever use such code in a solid project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this using `.map`. Firstly if we just start with your data in an array

```
let data = ["11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23"]
```

We need to perform the following steps.

1. Split each String in the array by ","
2. Split the substrings from the above result by the "-"
3. Check to see if the value is greater than 12, subtract 12 if needed
4. Join the convert the new values with a "-"
5. Join the result from above with a ","

When we use `split` on a `String` we get the following `[String.SubSequence]`, which we need to convert back into a `[String]` we can do this by performing a `.map { String($0) }` immediately after performing the `split`.

```
let data = ["11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23", "11-16,20-23"]

let result = data.map { $0
    .split(separator: ",")          // split each String item at the comma
    .map { String($0) }             // convert to String as we have subsequences
    .map { $0
        .split(separator: "-")      // Now split each string by  the dash
        .map { String($0) }         // convert to String
        .map(convertTime)           // use the above convert time function
        .joined(separator: "-")     // join the values with a dash
    }
    .joined(separator: ",")         // join the values with a comma
}

func convertTime(_ hour: String) -> String {
    // When casting to Int we get Int? so we need to unwrap it
    if let value = Int(hour), value > 12 {
        return String(value - 12)
    } else {
        return hour
    }
}


print(result) // ["11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11"]
```

You could make it simpler by using `.components(separatedBy:)`

```
let result = data.map { $0
    .components(separatedBy: ",")
    .map { $0
        .components(separatedBy: "-")       
        .map(convertTime)           
        .joined(separator: "-")     
    }
    .joined(separator: ",")         
}
```

## Update

Mapping to days of the week is possible. There are a couple of things that we need. Firstly, we need to make sure that the order of the data matches the order of the days of the week. If they do not match, or are not consistently ordered in the same way, then it would not be possible to map them.

Secondly, from your comment it looks like you want map them to a custom struct. So we need to create the struct

```
struct OpeningTimes {
    let day: String
    let fromWorkingHours: String
}
```

Then we can use our answer from above which outputs the updated hours to `result` and we can [zip](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-the-zip-function-to-join-two-arrays) it with an array of the days of the week. For ease I have just used the output from the above in the code below so that you have a contained example.

```
let result = ["11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11", "11-4,8-11"] 
let weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

let arrayOfOpeningTimes = zip(weekDays, result).map {
    OpeningTimes(day: $0.0, fromWorkingHours: $0.1)
}


print(arrayOfOpeningTimes)
```

This will create an array of `OpeningTimes`, just make sure that you have the same number of items in each array of week days and hours, otherwise there will be missing values.

Comment: Answer is right, but who would do that.. :)

Comment: @andrew I have 7 weekly days hours how to map the hours to weekdays

Comment: like : [{"day": "Sunday", "from_working_hours": "11-4,8-11"}]

Comment: That's do able but `from_working_hours` is not a convention for variable names in Swift. It should really be something like `fromWorkingHours`. I've updated my answer showing you how you can use `zip` to combine two arrays.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. for your clear explanation and the valuable answer

Answer (score 1):

```
func test() {
    let hours = "11-16,20-23|11-4,6-5|11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23|13-17,20-24|11-16,20-23|11-16,20-23"
    let split = hours.components(separatedBy: "|")
    var finalarray = [String]()
    for i in 0..<split.count {
        let splitedArray = split[i].components(separatedBy: ",")
        var array = [String]()
        for item in splitedArray {
            let tmpstr = item.split(separator: "-").compactMap {
                Int($0)
            }.map { "\($0 > 12 ? $0 - 12 : $0)"}.joined(separator: "-")
            array.append(tmpstr)
        }
        let str = array.joined(separator: ",")
        finalarray.append(str)
    }
    print(finalarray.joined(separator: "|"))
}
```

Comment: This just prints `["11-4,6-5"]` it doesn't convert all the items

Comment: I agree, this needs to be fixed

Comment: I fixed it. i thought he want to find < 12 hours data from array.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid code that is hard to understand or to long I think it's best to create to functions to handle part of the logic

```
//Handle the inner pair of open/close hours
func openHours(from string: String.SubSequence) -> (Int, Int)? {
    let values = string.split(separator: "-")
        .compactMap { Int($0) }
        .map { $0 > 12 ? $0 - 12 : $0 }

    guard values.count == 2 else { return nil }
    return (values[0], values[1])
}

//Handle am and pm opening hours string
func dayHours(from string: String.SubSequence) -> String {
    return string.split(separator: ",")
        .compactMap(openHours)
        .map { "\($0.0)-\($0.1)"}
        .joined(separator: ", ")
}
```

Then the actual conversion becomes quite simple

```
let output = hours.split(separator: "|")
    .map(dayHours)
```

To return this using a 12h format we need to change the openHours function

```
func openHours(from string: String.SubSequence) -> (String, String)? {
    let values = string.split(separator: "-")
        .compactMap { Int($0) }
        .map { $0 > 12 ? "\($0 - 12)pm" : "\($0)am" }

    guard values.count == 2 else { return nil }
    return (values[0], values[1])
}
```

Comment: How to concatenate the string. if great than 12 like 11PM

Comment: how to convert the output like [{"day": "Sunday", "from_working_hours": "11am-4pm,8pm-11pm"},{"day": "Monday", "from_working_hours": "11am-4pm,8pm-11pm"}]

Comment: Ask a new question